# Convert a pandas column containing tuples to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe `df` of 800 rows with one of its column containing tuples:

```
        conComb             insOrDel    supp
580     ('r', '>', 'ins')   36272       0.199807
449     ('ar', '>', 'ins')  31596       0.174049
594     ('tar', '>', 'ins') 4398        0.024227
529     ('lar', '>', 'ins') 3037        0.016730
```

`df.dtypes` results in the following

```
conComb      object
insOrDel      int64
supp        float64
dtype: object
```

I would like to convert the `conComb` column into a string. But use of

`df["conComb"] = df["conComb"].astype(str)`

`df["conComb"] = df["conComb"].astype(|S1)` or

`df["conComb"] = df["conComb"].values.astype(str)`,

does not change the type.

How can the type of the column `conComb` be changed to a string?

*Extension to the question as discussed in the comments*

Further, I have another dataframe `confDF` with 24,000 rows

```
    conComb                     objF    insOrDel
0   ('<ablucar', '>', 'ins')    (a)     11
1   ('<ablucar', '>', 'ins')    (ai)    3
2   ('<ablucar', '>', 'ins')    (ais)   3
3   ('<ablucar', '>', 'ins')    (amos)  2
```

Applying join operation between `df`and `confDF` throws the following message `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

```
confDF["conComb"] = confDF["conComb"].astype(str)
pd.DataFrame.join(df,confDF, on ="conComb")
```

How can this be rectified?

Comment: `df["conComb"] = df["conComb"].astype(str)`?

Comment: If use `df["conComb"].astype(str)` it corectly convert to string, check type `print (type(df['conComb'].iloc[0]))`

Comment: Try: ```df["conComb"]=df["conComb"].map(str)```

Comment: Do you want `('r', '>', 'ins')` to become `"('r', '>', 'ins')"` etc.?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski- Its the same effect as `astype`

Comment: @AndreasK.I want "('r', '>', 'ins')"

Comment: @jezrael The type for `(type(df['conComb'].iloc[0]))` is `str`. However, this is throwing a `valueError` when I am doing a join operation- Hence dtype needs to be `str`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is difference between `dtype`s and `type`s.

`string`s, `dict`s, `tuple`s and `list`s has same dtype `object`.

But each has different type.

For check `dtypes` is used:

```
print (df.dtypes)
```

For check types use :

```
print (df.iloc[0].apply(type))
```

EDIT: I think error is raised because `join` working by default with index values and column, if is specify `on` parameter.

SO I think if want join 2 Dataframes by 2 columns use:

```
confDF["conComb"] = confDF["conComb"].astype(str)
df1 = pd.merge(df,confDF, on ="conComb", how='left')
```

Or:

```
confDF["conComb"] = confDF["conComb"].astype(str)
df1 = df.set_index('conComb').join(confDF, on ="conComb")
```

Comment: The type for `(type(df['conComb'].iloc[0]))` is `str`. However, this is throwing a `valueError` when I am doing a join operation- Hence dtype needs to be str @jezrael

Comment: @AmrithKrishna Can you explain more? what is another values for join?

Comment: Updated the question to elaborate on the scenario @jezrael