# python pandas - Convert a column of tuples to string column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, tuples

This should be a relatively simple question.

Below is the sample of my `df` column:

```
             title2
1      (, 2 ct, , )
2      (, 1 ct, , )
3      (, 2 ct, , )
4               NaN
5      (, 2 ct, , )
6     (, 5 ct, , )
7  (, 7 ounce, , )
8    (, 1 gal, , )
9              NaN
10             NaN
```

I would like to convert the whole column to a proper string column - i.e. my desired output would be:

```
    title2
1      2ct
2      1ct
3      2ct
4      NaN
5      2ct
6      5ct
7  7 ounce
8     1gal
9      NaN
10     NaN
```

I have tried the following commands, but none seem to work:

```
title['title3'] = title['title2'].agg(' '.join)
title['title3'] = title['title2'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))
title['title3'] = title['title2'].astype(str)
title['title3'] = title['title2'].values.astype(str)
```

The answer given in this post: [Convert a pandas column containing tuples to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362062/convert-a-pandas-column-containing-tuples-to-string), also does not help me unfortunately.

Can some shed some light on this? Thank you all.

Comment: `df['title2'].str.join(' ').str.strip()` ?

Comment: Are these 'tuples' saved as string in your column cells?

Comment: @shubhamSharma yours worked! I had a feeling this would be much simpler than I expected.

Comment: In any case, thank you both for assisting.

Comment: whats wrong with a simple regex ? `df['title2'].replace('[(,\s+,)]','',regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. I assume that tuples and Nans are saved as strings in your column, if not let me know so that i will adjust solution:

```
def clear(x):
    if x=='Nan':
        return 'Nan'
    else:
        l=str(x)
        l=[i.strip() for i in l.split(',')]
        return [i for i in l if any(k in ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9') for k in i)][0]

df['title2']=df['title2'].apply(lambda x: clear(x))
```

Comment: Megale, unfortunately your code above gives me something like ```("", ("",("".....```

Comment: Now it gives me the error ```list index out of range```. I don't think it's your fault though, I think it's because I only posted a sample of 10 rows from a column of ~7k rows... So there are probably other stuff to be taken into consideration. Nonetheless, the simple code in the comments above gave me the answer I am looking for so don't worry about this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
demo_data['title2'] = demo_data['title2'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x.lstrip("\,\'\[ \(").rstrip(" \, \,\'\]\)"))
demo_data['title2'] = demo_data['title2'].str.replace(r"\', \'", ",")
demo_data['title2']= demo_data['title2'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x.lstrip("\,\'\[ \(").rstrip(" \, \,\'\]\)"))
demo_data['title2'] = demo_data['title2'].str.replace(r" ", "")
```

which gives.

```
   ID  title2
0   1     2ct
1   2     1ct
2   3     2ct
3   4     nan
4   5     2ct
5   6     5ct
6   7  7ounce
7   8    1gal
8   9     nan
9  10     nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
import re

df['title3'] = df['title2'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '', str(x)))
```