# How to add two dataframes with tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tuples

I am extracting data from a Databank and storing it in a dictionary. Then I convert this dictionary into a DataFrame. I am left with two DataFrames, which I'd like to add but the data is stored in tuples.

Both DataFrames are really big (66 rows x 8497 columns) but look something like this:

df1

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P00001 | (-17.5,) | (-16.2,) | (-15.9,) | (-14.3,) |
| P00002 | (-11.3,) | (-13.1,) | (-13.8,) | (-10.4,) |
| P00003 | (-17.0,) | (-18.0,) | (-17.6,) | (-13.6,) |
| P00004 | None | None | None | None |

df2

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P00001 | (3.3,) | (3.8,) | (5.6,) | (7.5,) |
| P00002 | (4.2,) | (2.3,) | (1.5,) | (5.3,) |
| P00003 | (0.0,) | (0.0,) | (0.0,) | (0.0,) |
| P00004 | (2.8,) | (3.7,) | (4.8,) | (3.9,) |

I'd like to add for example the value (P00001,0) in df1 = -17.5 with the value (P00001,0) in df2 = 3.3 and so on, so that it looks like this:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P00001 | -14.2 | -12.4 | -10.3 | -6.8 |
| P00002 | -7.1 | -10.8 | -12.3 | -5.1 |
| P00003 | -17.0 | -18.0 | -17.6 | -13.6 |
| P00004 | 2.8 | 3.7 | 4.8 | 3.9 |

I have tried:

`df_add = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)`

`tuple(np.add(df1,df2))`

`tuple(map(sum,zip(df1,df2)))`

I also tried turning the dataframe into int, but that didn't work either.

`df1_new = df1[:].astype(int)`

`df_new = df1.convert_dtypes(int)`

`df_new = df1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')`

I am a beginner, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Do you want something like this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65409122/python-pandas-convert-a-column-of-tuples-to-string-column

Comment: please provide your input as DataFrame constructor for reproducibility and also the expected output

Comment: Sounds like you want `df1.apply(lambda x: x.str[0]).astype(float)` (provided you can guarantee each tuple has one and only one member)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforming the tuples to integers is indeed an option:

```
import numpy as np

def tuple2int(x):
    try:
        return x[0]
   except:
       return 0

df1[:] = np.vectorize(tuple2int)(df1)
df2[:] = np.vectorize(tuple2int)(df2)
```

Then add the data frames as you suggested:

```
df_add = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```